# Disable Google Indexing the HTTPS version of our website naked domain

Tags: google-app-engine, https, indexing, google-search

We're on Google App Engine, and due to some technicalities, we're unable to serve on https://feeltracker.com

We know that  http://feeltracker.com and http://www.feeltracker.com work fine however.

How can we ensure Google doesn't index https://feeltracker.com as it is currently doing, and instead indexes http://feeltracker.com or http://www.feeltracker.com?

Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: This is a valid question, since http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612627/naked-domain-redirect-failing-when-using-https-ssl-on-google-app-engine doesn't provide a solution to apps on google app engine. Other app engine developers must have experienced this as well.

Comment: You are serving on https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAE doesn't officially support naked domains. What you're seeing is a limitation of GAE,  https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general#naked_domain