# Google App Engine, custom domain and SSL error

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to setup Google App Engine with custom domain and SSL.

I've added the certificates to Google Apps and added the custom domains to Google App Engine.

I can successfully access `http://domain.com` and `https://domain-com.appspot.com` but when I try to access `https://www.domain.com` I got the following error: `This webpage is not available`

The domain is `lonardiDOTorg`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try https://www.domain.com ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28149518/google-apps-app-engine-https-version-of-naked-domain-does-not-redirect

Comment: Hi Kekito, yes I tried the domain with www and it doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some research, my findings show that this isn't supported for the moment being.

[Issue 10802](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10802&q=SSL%20naked%20domain&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log) on the Google App Engine issue tracker seems to confirm that it isn't yep available at the moment.

This [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612627/naked-domain-redirect-failing-when-using-https-ssl-on-google-app-engine/19645235) seems to contain the different workarounds that other users have used.

I hope this helps.

---

It is very challenging to help with this kind of issue without being able to inspect the domain and app itself.

Are there any privacy concerns in sharing the domain name so that we can see if the page is being returned by Google or by your DNS provider? It may be possible that the DNS records aren't set correctly.

Keep in mind that as this configuration is done on the Google Apps side, the Apps team may be able to assist if you have a Apps for Business account. This could help get assistance without sharing any information.

Apps Help Center: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2644334
Apps Contact Page: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2644334#contact=1

Comment: Hi Bero, I've added the domain in the question. Thanks

Comment: Bero, I'm not trying to use SSL on the naked domain, the www would be good enough but it's not working either.