# how to set https for naked domain?

Tags: https, openshift, domain-name

I have been using openshift for quite some time. Since letsencrypt is in beta, I thought I gave it a try.
My current setup:
`www.digrin.com` is an alias to my openshift url - `digrin-digrincom.rhcloud.com`
`digrin.com` A tag points to wwwizer redirect service `174.129.25.170`.
I have uploaded ssl certificates to openshift. It works fine on domain `www.digrin.com`. However since naked domain `digrin.com` points to wwwizer.com, it does not use https. I believe it is a problem. I want both domains (naked as well as www variant) to use https. Is it possible? I know wwwizer has some premium plan where it might be possible, but I would like a free version if possible.
If you don't know, I can not set cname for naked domain, so I had to use A tag to wwwizer, because openshift might change IP address.
**Useful link:**
[How to use naked GoDaddy domain with OpenShift hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23169529/how-to-use-naked-godaddy-domain-with-openshift-hosting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all I had to generate ssl certificate for naked domain - digrin.com. I set temporarily A tag for digrin.com to openshift's ip and generated ssl certificate.
Now we have working certificate, but since A tag for digrin can not be set permanently, domain registrant must support `naked domain redirect`. More on this you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612627/naked-domain-redirect-failing-when-using-https-ssl-on-google-app-engine) -> if you registrant does not support it, move to [cloudfront](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23169529/how-to-use-naked-godaddy-domain-with-openshift-hosting) (I will test cloudfront if my registrant will not add this feature within few months and will update this answer).

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a free (1 domain) service that redirects naked domains with valid SSL certificates. I moved from wwwizer to [nakedssl](https://www.nakedssl.com/) to redirect to an Opensift server and it works fine.